# Linux "screen" does not write results

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have an Ubuntu system running on a remote computer that I use for computations. On other machines whenever I want to run some time-consuming program I type:

```
screen
```

and execute my program in the resulting screen, say:

```
./myprogram input.xml
```

The program in question writes some results to an output file. This works fine on other machines.

When I try the same in the remote computer, everything is the same apart from one thing. If I close the window where the screen is running, my program stop writing results to an output file (it will also stop reading files from disk). As long as I look at the terminal window where the screen is running and the program is executing, there are no problems.

Can anyone offer some insight into why this happens and how it may be fixed?

Comment: This belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you reconnect to it with `screen -r`, does it continue when you do that?

Comment: I suspect it's not installed correctly on that machine, try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
nohup & ./myprogram input.xml
```

Or rather `disown`,

```
disown & ./myprogram input.xml
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary when using `screen` -- that's one of its main points.

Comment: I agree it should not be necessary but I have to deal with the realities. Thanks for syggestion Skynet. I will try it out immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried it out, and it worked. Thank you!